# How best way to rsync from aws s3 to gcloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, s3cmd

I must execute a **rsync** ( not only copy or move ) from all my buckets from s3 to google cloud. 
I need create the same infraestructure of s3 to google.
I have like 2Tera in s3, and all days I receive new files..

My solution today is

gsutil rsync -r -m s3://bucket gs://bucket

But this solution is slower .

Do you have an ideia to faster?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have lots of files in S3 this is going to be very slow no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

If you are synchronizing a large amount of data between clouds you might consider setting up a Google Compute Engine account and running gsutil there. Since cross-provider gsutil data transfers flow through the machine where gsutil is running, doing this can make your transfer run significantly faster than running gsutil on your local workstation.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

Answer (score 1):

The up to date answer to this question is to use [Google Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/):

> **What is Storage Transfer Service?**
>
> Storage Transfer Service transfers
>   data from an online data source to a data sink. Your data source can
>   be an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket, an HTTP/HTTPS
>   location, or a Cloud Storage bucket. Your data sink (the destination)
>   is always a Cloud Storage bucket.